# How to add query param from object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
//example of an Object
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50
};
```

**Expected output :**
URL  : `www.domain.com/person?firstName=John&lastName=Doe&age=50`

what is the best way to add it in query param ?

Comment: How about this for the last part , `Object.entries(person).map(k=>k.join("=")).join('&')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take `entries` of the object then we can `map` and `join` it accordingly. Give this a try:

```js
var person = { firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50 };

var result = `www.domain.com/person?${Object.entries(person).map(k=>k.join("=")).join('&')}`;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this method :

```
 getQueryParamURL(url, param) {
        let query = '?'
        Object.keys(param).forEach((key, i, arr) => {
            query += key + '=' + param[key]
            if (arr[i + 1]) {
                query += '&';
            }
        })
        return url + query
    }
```

**Use it :**

```
let personObj = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50
};
let queryUrl = this.getQueryParamURL('www.domain.com/person',personObj )
```